# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. sql t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that inserts data into a database table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Party_Master]([ACOpen_Date_Time],[DOB],[UID_MF],[UID_Equity],[Party_Name],[Ref_Name],[Address],[Area],[City],[Occuption],[MF_Cat],[MF_M_Update],[EQ_Cat],[Total_Life_Sum_Assured],[Term_Insurance],[Mediclaim],[Top_Up],[PA_Policy],[Traditional_Insurance],[Vehical_Insurance],[FD],[Ex_Traders],[Is_IPO],[Is_Bond_FD],[SIP],[FP_Done],[FP_Date_Time],[Is_Map_NJ],[Is_Exection],[portfolio_review],[Diwali_Gift],[Diwali_Gift_Area],[Last_Call],[Is_Couriour],[Page_No_Couriour_File],[Active],[Zone_Id],[Ph_Lable1],[Ph_No1],[Ph_Lable2],[Ph_No2],[Ph_Lable3],[Ph_No3],[Ph_Lable4],[Ph_No4],[Handover_To],[Entry_By],[Entry_Date_Time],[View_By],[Lat],[Long],[Email_ID],[Website],[Extra1],[Extra2],[Extra3],[Group_Head],[Last_Visit_Date]) 
VALUES ('', '','', '123','SHALIN B GAJJAR', 'Nishidh Bhai', '', 'Rambaug', '', 'JOB', 'Silver', '12/31/2020', 'Gold' , N'500000' , N'22000' , N'10000' , N'0' , N'0' , N'0' , N'0' , N'400000' , '1' , '1' , '1' , N'5000' , N'0' , '' , '1' , '1' , '12/30/2020' , '' , '' , '12/30/2020' , '' , '' , '1' , '' , 'SHALIN B GAJJAR' , '9898683714' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 1 , 'GETDATE()' , 'M1' , '' , '' , 'shalinbgajjar7008@gmail.com' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'GETDATE()')
```

When I run this query in Management Studio, I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

What is wrong with this query? Please help me

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Party_Master]
(
    [Pk_PartyID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ACOpen_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [UID_MF] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UID_Equity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Party_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ref_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Area] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Occuption] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [MF_Cat] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [MF_M_Update] [datetime] NULL,
    [EQ_Cat] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Total_Life_Sum_Assured] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Term_Insurance] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Mediclaim] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Top_Up] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [PA_Policy] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Traditional_Insurance] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Vehical_Insurance] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [FD] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Ex_Traders] [bit] NULL,
    [Is_IPO] [bit] NULL,
    [Is_Bond_FD] [bit] NULL,
    [SIP] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [FP_Done] [bit] NULL,
    [FP_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Is_Map_NJ] [bit] NULL,
    [Is_Exection] [bit] NULL,
    [portfolio_review] [datetime] NULL,
    [Diwali_Gift] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Diwali_Gift_Area] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Last_Call] [datetime] NULL,
    [Is_Couriour] [bit] NULL,
    [Page_No_Couriour_File] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [Zone_Id] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Ph_Lable1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ph_No1] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Ph_Lable2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ph_No2] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Ph_Lable3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ph_No3] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Ph_Lable4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ph_No4] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Handover_To] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Entry_By] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Entry_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [View_By] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Lat] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Long] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Email_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Website] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Extra1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Extra2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Extra3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Group_Head] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Last_Visit_Date] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Party_Master] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Pk_PartyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is my table schema

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for `Party_Master`.

Comment: A clue to get you started - `'GETDATE()'` is _not_ a date. Those `'` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Also, don't do dates like '12/31/2020' - do them like '20201231' so they work reliably.

Comment: This looks really un-normalized

Comment: Looks like the issue might be happening due to N' if the columns you are trying inserting are integer as others already suggested please share the create table script for debugging.

Comment: @roshaga please see my update..

Comment: Why are you storing `''` in a datetime column? You are aware that means 1st Jan 1900?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below insert will work. The issue were few issues

1. you were trying to insert '' in numeric column.
2. you were enforcing nvarchar by N' in numeric column
3. for current date it should be getdate with out quotes as others have pointed out
4. Bit column does not needs quotes

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[party_master] 
                ([acopen_date_time], 
                 [dob], 
                 [uid_mf], 
                 [uid_equity], 
                 [party_name], 
                 [ref_name], 
                 [address], 
                 [area], 
                 [city], 
                 [occuption], 
                 [mf_cat], 
                 [mf_m_update], 
                 [eq_cat], 
                 [total_life_sum_assured], 
                 [term_insurance], 
                 [mediclaim], 
                 [top_up], 
                 [pa_policy], 
                 [traditional_insurance], 
                 [vehical_insurance], 
                 [fd], 
                 [ex_traders], 
                 [is_ipo], 
                 [is_bond_fd], 
                 [sip], 
                 [fp_done], 
                 [fp_date_time], 
                 [is_map_nj], 
                 [is_exection], 
                 [portfolio_review], 
                 [diwali_gift], 
                 [diwali_gift_area], 
                 [last_call], 
                 [is_couriour], 
                 [page_no_couriour_file], 
                 [active], 
                 [zone_id], 
                 [ph_lable1], 
                 [ph_no1], 
                 [ph_lable2], 
                 [ph_no2], 
                 [ph_lable3], 
                 [ph_no3], 
                 [ph_lable4], 
                 [ph_no4], 
                 [handover_to], 
                 [entry_by], 
                 [entry_date_time], 
                 [view_by], 
                 [lat], 
                 [long], 
                 [email_id], 
                 [website], 
                 [extra1], 
                 [extra2], 
                 [extra3], 
                 [group_head], 
                 [last_visit_date]) 
    VALUES      ('', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '123', 
                 'SHALIN B GAJJAR', 
                 'Nishidh Bhai', 
                 '', 
                 'Rambaug', 
                 '', 
                 'JOB', 
                 'Silver', 
                 '12/31/2020', 
                 'Gold', 
                 500000 , 
                  22000 , 
                 10000, 
                 0, 
                 0, 
                  0, 
                  0 , 
                 400000, 
                 1, 
                 1, 
                 1, 
                 5000, 
                 0, 
                 '', 
                 1, 
                 1, 
                 getdate(), 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 getdate(), 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 1, 
                 null, 
                 'SHALIN B GAJJAR', 
                 '9898683714', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 null, 
                 1, 
                 GETDATE(), 
                 'M1', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 'shalinbgajjar7008@gmail.com', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 '', 
                 null, 
                 GETDATE())
```

Comment: tnks a lot.. you save my time..

Comment: You may as well fix up the date values (to YYYYMMDD) while you are there.